# User-defined function that will rename a variable in a named column in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to write a function that will rename variables across multiple columns inside of a data table in R.

My data table is structured similar to this:

| feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| var_a | var_c | var_b | var_a |
| var_b | var_a | var_a | var_c |
| var_c | var_b | var_c | var_b |

I'm trying to rename all the variables to new name. Some of them are in feature1 for one item, but in feature4 for another item but the naming would be the same across the data frame.

| feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| new_a | new_c | new_b | new_a |
| new_b | new_a | new_a | new_c |
| new_c | new_b | new_c | new_b |

I'm just having trouble writing my own user-defined function to do this in less lines of code than a standard `dat$feature1\[dat$feature1 == 'var_a'\] \*\<- '\*new_a'`.

Preferably I'd like to pass through something along the lines of `function(dat, var_a, new_a)` or something where I can just pass through a list of my old and new variables.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you say *"inside of a data table"*, do you mean that you are using the `data.table` package and this is a `data.table` class object? Or is it a regular `data.frame`?

Comment: @GregorThomas sorry should have specified that it is a data.table the "df" is just a force of habit.

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("var","new", x))
```

Output:

```
#   feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
# 1    new_a    new_c    new_b    new_a
# 2    new_b    new_a    new_a    new_c
# 3    new_c    new_b    new_c    new_b
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "feature1   feature2    feature3    feature4
var_a   var_c   var_b   var_a
var_b   var_a   var_a   var_c
var_c   var_b   var_c   var_b", header = TRUE)
df <- data.table::data.table(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `across`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(1:4, ~ sub(".*(_)", "new\\1", .x)))
  feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
1    new_a    new_c    new_b    new_a
2    new_b    new_a    new_a    new_c
3    new_c    new_b    new_c    new_b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that takes in a data frame, the old string and its replacement.

```
library(tidyverse)

replace_func <- function(df, var, new_var) {
  df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x %>%
                    str_replace_all(var, new_var)))
}

replace_func(df, "var", "new")

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 new_a    new_c    new_b    new_a   
2 new_b    new_a    new_a    new_c   
3 new_c    new_b    new_c    new_b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[, lapply(.SD, sub, pattern = "var", replacement = "new", fixed = TRUE)]
#    feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4
# 1:    new_a    new_c    new_b    new_a
# 2:    new_b    new_a    new_a    new_c
# 3:    new_c    new_b    new_c    new_b
```

Using this sample data:

```
library(data.table)
df = fread(text = 'feature1     feature2    feature3    feature4
var_a   var_c   var_b   var_a
var_b   var_a   var_a   var_c
var_c   var_b   var_c   var_b')
```